# Hashtag text is appending to the title of the website

Tags: jquery, html

I  have the following html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Service Catalog</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="pure-menu pure-menu-open pure-menu-horizontal">
<ul id="list">
    <li id="view1"><a href="#view1">All Services</a></li>
    <li id="view2"><a href="#view2">Top 15</a></li>
 </ul>
```

...

jquery:

```
$('ul li').click(function(e) 
    { 
       var tab;
       tab = $(this).attr('id');  
       selectTab(tab);
       buildTable(tab);
    });
```

When ever I click on a tab the href is appended to the title of the window.
for example:

the title would like this Service Catalogue#view2#view2#view1 if I click on the tabs multiple times.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

use e.preventDefault() inside your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `e.preventDefault()` or  `return false;`

```
 $('ul li').click(function(e) 
{ 
   var tab;
   tab = $(this).attr('id');  
   selectTab(tab);
   buildTable(tab);
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Both of these work fine when a user goes directly to the page for example: http://mypage/index.html however when you go directly to a tab for example http://mypage/index.html#view1 and then if you click on the tabs again...it will again append each tab hash to the window title. :(